# Pass Class as an Argument to page.evaluate in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

In Puppeteer, `page.evaluate` throws an error if I pass a class as an argument.

It works for regular objects though.

**Is there some workaround to make it work?**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
});
let page = await browser.newPage();
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 3;
    }
}
await page.evaluate((SomeClass) => {
    let object = new SomeClass();
    console.log(object.a);
}, SomeClass);
})();
```

Comment: Answer depends on **how would you evaluate a class**? Define that and edit the question to include this information and I'll help you reach a working solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a similar problem if you try to pass a function. I've seen people stringifying the function to pass it to puppeteer to make it work, so in your case I'd do this using eval. Many people think eval is evil, maybe there is a better way, but at least it's a possible workaround.

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 3;
    }
}    
await page.evaluate((strSomeClass) => {
    eval("window.SomeClass = " + strSomeClass);
    let object = new SomeClass();
    console.log(object.a);
}, SomeClass.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) by passing an *instance* of the object, rather then the object itself, to [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.6.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
await page.evaluate(object => {
  console.log(object.a);
}, new SomeClass);
```

Your full program should look something like this:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
      this.a = 3;
    }
  }

  await page.evaluate(object => {
    console.log(object.a);
  }, new SomeClass);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: This won't work in general. For example, when the constructor calls some browser-specific function I have to instantiate the class in the browser and not in node.

Comment: @yewang It works in the vast majority of situations for classes that make sense to be passed to the Page DOM Environment. If the constructor is calling a Page DOM-specific function, then it really shouldn't be available outside the Page DOM Environment. The same could be said if the constructor called a Puppeteer-specific function that was only available in the Node.js environment. Understand the two different environments, and determine how to structure your class accordingly.