# TypeScript + Playwright/Puppeteer Test Tab communication

Tags: typescript, testing, puppeteer, playwright

I tried to test my demo broadcastChannel module with playwright. But I cannot pass `Class` to `evaluate` or inject class instance to `Window`. Below is the minimal reproducible example.

**utils.ts**

```js
export class Utils {
  public static formatTime() { return new Date().toLocaleString(); }
  public static generateRandomStr() { /* generate random str logic*/ }
}
```

**index.ts**

```js
import { Utils } from "./utils";

export class Channel<T extends string> {
  private uniqueID = Utils.generateRandomStr();
  private channel: BroadcastChannel;

  constructor(name: T) {
    this.channel = new BroadcastChannel(name);
    this.onMessage();
  }

  private onMessage() {
    this.channel.addEventListener("message", e => {
      console.log(e.data);
    });
  }

  public sendMsg(msg: any) {
    this.channel.postMessage({
      id: this.uniqueID,
      time: Utils.formatTime(),
      msg,
    });
  }

  public sendHelloWorld() {
    this.sendMsg("Hello World");
  }

  public sendByeWorld() {
    this.sendMsg("Bye World");
  }
}
```

According to @Sheldon Oliveira's answer and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356599/12644421), I got that there's no easy way to pass `Class` or class instance to `evaluate`. Maybe I went for the wrong way to test tab communication, I hope there's a better solution.

Below are the two different approches I tried.

```js
import { test, expect, Page } from '@playwright/test';
import { Channel } from '../src/index';

let page1: Page, page2: Page;
test.beforeEach(async ({ context }) => {
  [page1, page2] = await Promise.all([context.newPage(), context.newPage()]);
  await Promise.all([page1.goto("https://www.google.com"), page2.goto("https://www.google.com")]);
});

test.afterEach(async ({ context }) => {
  await Promise.all([page1.close(), page2.close()]);
  await context.close();
});

test('sendHelloWorld', async () => {
  await Promise.all([
    await page1.evaluate((strClass) => {
      eval("window.Channel = " + strClass);
      window.channel = new window.Channel();
      //                     ^ReferenceError: _Utils is not defined
    }, Channel.toString()),
    await page2.evaluate((strClass) => {
      eval("window.Channel = " + strClass);
      window.channel = new window.Channel();
      //                     ^ReferenceError: _Utils is not defined
    }, Channel.toString()),
  ]);

  const msgPromise = page2.waitForEvent("console");
  await page1.evaluate(() => {
    window.channel.sendHelloWorld();
  });
  const msg = await msgPromise;
  expect((await msg.args()[0].jsonValue()).msg).toBe("Hello World");
});

test('sendByeWorld', async () => {
  await Promise.all([
    await page1.evaluate((channel) => {
      window.channel = channel;
      //             ^ no prototype method sendByeWorld
    }, new Channel()),
    await page2.evaluate((channel) => {
      window.channel = channel;
      //             ^ no prototype method sendByeWorld
    }, new Channel()),
  ]);

  const msgPromise = page2.waitForEvent("console");
  await page1.evaluate(() => {
    window.channel.sendHelloWorld();
  });
  const msg = await msgPromise;
  expect((await msg.args()[0].jsonValue()).msg).toBe("Bye World");
});
```

The expect console trick is from [playwright documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-consolemessage).

I also added `puppeteer` tag, cause I think the problem is the same regardless of the framework.

Comment: First things first. What are you trying to achieve by passing an class as an argument? If you explain the use case/requirement in bit detail, somebody might be able to suggest an more direct solution.

Comment: What is the precise automation test scenario you are dealing with this?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Thoroughly re-construct the question, thanks for the advice~

Comment: I also found [broadcast-channel repo](https://github.com/pubkey/broadcast-channel/blob/4070ac651d0ddaddb2bd961c8a0ce32fa348eaa7/test/e2e.test.js#L33-L77) as a reference, but I didn't find any send or receive logic.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; you can not use a class as a parameter for evaluate.

docs:
[This argument can be a mix of Serializable values and JSHandle or ElementHandle instances.](https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating#evaluation-argument:%7E:text=This%20argument%20can%20be%20a%20mix%20of%20Serializable%20values%20and%20JSHandle%20or%20ElementHandle%20instances.)

A class is not a serializable value.